# Add static blocks into certain columns in magento

Tags: magento, static, block

I have a site with a 3 column layout. In the left is a menu where you can select the products, in the middle is an image slider. Now, i created another static block, but how can i add it into the right column?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1] In page.xml add below code. I think you've that code in it.

```
        <block type="core/text_list" name="right" as="right" translate="label">
            <label>Right Column</label>
        </block>
```

2] And in your 3columns.phtml add below code after your left column

```
<div class="col-right sidebar">
   <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?>
</div>
```

Comment: If answer is worked then marking an answer to correct or up vote would appreciate the contributer. Thanks.

Comment: i'm not able to upvote due to my low reputation :( sorry